# How to load test a ruby on rails app running with Puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jmeter, puma, http-status-code-429

My team and I are trying to load test a ruby on rails web app with a puma web server using JMeter to generate the load. The problem is, we always get about 98% error rate and all of those are 429 Too many requests errors. Does any of you had the same problem before ?

Edit: Requests were blocked by Rack-Attack.

Comment: I think you need to find out where in the stack this response is being generated, does it come from Puma? Does it come from rack (e.g. from rack-attack gem)? Or (seems unlikely) from Rails itself?

Comment: Thank you so much !! Rack-attack was the one who was blocking us